# SystemVerilog 2-bit register decoding problem

Tags: system-verilog, flip-flop, register-transfer-level

I have two 2-bit inputs and an output of 1-bit. So what I'm trying to do is code a next state value with taking AND of the two inputs, then use non-blocking <= to assign that value into register xy_r, which is now two D-flipflops. So I am seeking to get always the XOR-value of the xy_r previous clock edge as my output xor_out. I suppose that the way below is not the right one?

It worked in the simulation but then again in RTL Synthesis I didn't end up with an XOR gate but a third flip-flop so it seems like xor_out is treated as a register.

I suppose I can't use assign outside of the if-else-statements because in that case the output wouldn't follow the xy_r previous state but the present.

Can you please assist me how to solve this issue, if there is a somewhat simple way.

```
    module 2ffsxor
  (input logic clk,
   input logic       rst_n,
   input logic [1:0] x_in,
   input logic [1:0] y_in,   
   output logic      xor_out
   );

   logic [1:0]       xy;
   logic [1:0]       xy_r;

   always @ (posedge clk or negedge rst_n)
    begin
    if (rst_n == '0)
      xy_r <= '0;
    else
      begin
         xy = x_in & y_in;
         xy_r <= xy;
         xor_out = xy_r[0] ^ xy_r[1];
      end   
    end
endmodule
```

And here's a schematic what it should be:
[Schematic 2ffsxor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1f9l3.png)

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I've tried this but the problem is that the synthesis treats xor_out as an half adder instead of just XOR gate. Also the xor_out would follow the xy_r on the same clock edge which is not the purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Synthesis treats this code as if you had wrote

```
 begin
         xy_r    <= x_in & y_in;
         xor_out <= xy_r[0] ^ xy_r[1];
 end
```

That's two stages of registers. But since you assigned `xor_out` with a blocking assignment, you have a simulation race condition for any process that tries to read `xor_out`. The race would be from the result from the previous values of `xy_r` and the result before that!

If you use an continuous assign statement outside this always block, any process reading `xor_out` on the clock edge will see the result from the previous state of `xy_r`.

But why not write this as on register:

```
 always @ (posedge clk or negedge rst_n)
    begin
    if (rst_n == '0)
      xor_out <= '0;
    else
      begin
         xy = x_in & y_in;
         xor_out <= xy[0] ^ xy[1];
      end   
    end
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. That could work, yeah but I'm trying to do it like in the schematic I just updated to my first post. And if I use continuous assignment outside the always block, the result of the xor_out contains the xy_r on the same clock edge.

Comment: You are incorrect about the continuous assignment outside the `always` block. Try it and see what it synthesizes.